# CDOSys having issue with multiple attachments

Tags: email

I have been using CDOSys object for email sending in Classic ASP and it's work well with single file attachment but does not work correctly for multiple attachments.It takes the name and file extension of last attachment file for all attachments.Please let me know where is the issue.Below is my code

```
Function Send_Email_WithAttachments(strFrom,strTo,strSubject,strBody,strCC,strBCC,arrFiles,arrText)
Dim mailObj,I
Set mailObj=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
With mailObj
.Subject=strSubject
.From=strFrom
.To=strTo
If isValidEmail(strCC) = True Then
.CC = strCC
End If 
If isValidEmail(strBCC) = True Then
.BCc = strBCC
End If 
.HTMLBody = strBody
If IsArray(arrFiles) = True Then
For I=0 To UBound(arrFiles)
.AddAttachment arrFiles(I)
 With mailObj.Attachments(1).Fields
.Item(cdoContentDisposition) = "attachment;filename="&arrText(I)
.Update
End With
Next
End If
.Send
End With
Set mailObj=Nothing
End Function


Thanks, Ravi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You address the same attachement (index==1) within the loop here:

```
With mailObj.Attachments(1).Fields
```

it should be;

```
With mailObj.Attachments(I).Fields
```